# carry & marry [pronunciation]

Tags: phonetics, pronunciation

Merriam Webster's dictionary provides two pronunciations for the word carry (\ˈka-rē, ˈker-ē\ ) as well as for marry ( \ˈmer-ē, ˈma-rē\ ). In both cases, the one I hear the most is the pronunciation with [e], i.e., \ˈker-ē\ and \ˈmer-ē\ .

Is this correct? Is this pronunciation with [e] for words like *carry* and *marry* the most common in American English?

Comment: Once again, M-W makes it unclear. Both _carry_ and _marry_ (as well as _Mary_ and _merry_) are pronounced with a fairly lax [ɛɹ] in most American lects. It's only some Northeastern US lects that differentiate /'meri, 'mɛri, 'mæri/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is correct that at least two pronunciations exist across all speakers of American English. There is no reliable data on frequency of particular pronunciations, and MW certainly hasn't conducted large-scale sociolinguistic surveys. In my dialect, I just have Xɛɹi (*mary, marry, merry* etc), and I know people who distinguish [meɹi] "Mary", [mɛɹi] "merry", [mæɹi] "marry", at least I think that is the sound / spelling correlation. I'm not an expert on what constitutes a rhyme (you learn that stuff in junior high and then it fades), but that a disyllable can't rhyme with a monosyllable, so "petty" and "pet" can't rhyme, nor can "airy" and "air".

Comment: In Midwestern American English, all tense-lax vowel distinctions neutralize before /r/, and /æ/ merges with both /ɛ/ and /e/. The only rhotic stressed nuclei are /ir, er, ar, or, ur, ʌr/, plus triphthongs /ayr, awr/ . The syllable boundary lies right in the middle of intervocalic /r/s, so how you hyphenate them is up to you.

Comment: @user6726 Sorry, the rhyme question was not the most appropriate. What I meant to ask was if both _marry_ and _carry_ are also pronounced with the same vowel sound as in _air_ or as in _merry_. Thanks for your answer.